# PHP/MySQL - Get Winning Streak

Tags: php, mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to display a user winning streak, but I am struggling to get my head around how I would write it - even the concept.

Here is an example (from newest to oldest) db:

```
id | win_id| loss_id| player id
1  |  123  | 999    | 123
2  |  123  | 999    | 123
3  |  999  | 123    | 123
4  |  123  | 999    | 123
```

So what I want to display is the winning streak for the player_id: 123 - so, it should echo '2' for the winning streak, because there was an interruption where the user lost on id 3

Comment: What does column `player_id` represents, compared to `win_id` and `loss_id`?

Comment: sorry, thats just the user it would be assigned to, so you could get all the games played by that user e.g. SELECT * FROM xx WHERE player_id = 123

Comment: group by loss_id=999?

Comment: Player 123 had (win, win, loss, win), in that order and his streak is 2? i.e. the most number of consecutive wins regardless of time. If player had ( win,win,loss,win,win,win,loss,win,loss,win,win) win streak is 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution for the current win streak : find all the matches where player win, but only if no defeat occurs later :

```
SELECT COUNT(t.id)
  FROM table t
 WHERE t.player_id = 123
   AND t.win_id = 123 /* player 123 won */
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                    FROM table t2
                   WHERE t2.player_id = 123
                     AND t2.win_id <> 123 /* player 123 lost */
                 AND t2.id > t.id /* lost occur after the win we look at */
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question as a gaps-and-island problem, where you want to group together "adjacent" rows.

Here is an approach using the difference between row numbers to define the groups (this requires MySQL 8.0); then, we can aggregate by winning streaks, sort by descending streak length and keep the top streak only:

```
select win_id, count(*) no_wins, min(id) start_id, max(id) end_id
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by player_id order by id) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by player_id, win_id order by id) rn2
    from mytable t
    where player_id = 123
) t
where win_id = 123
group by win_id, rn1 - rn2
order by no_wins desc
limit 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dHkU9mNW9f1hpc4iVtbAqT/2)**:

```
| win_id | no_wins | start_id | end_id |
| ------ | ------- | -------- | ------ |
| 123    | 2       | 1        | 2      |
```

Answer (score 1):

This would show the highest  winstreaks for user 123
It works with mysql 5.x

I added some data to show what it does

> ```
> CREATE TABLE wintable (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `win_id` INTEGER,
>   `loss_id` INTEGER,
>   `player id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO wintable
>   (`id`, `win_id`, `loss_id`, `player id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '123', '999', '123'),
>   ('2', '123', '999', '123'),
>     ('3', '123', '777', '123'),
>   ('4', '123', '777', '123'),
>   ('5', '999', '123', '123'),
>   ('6', '123', '999', '123'),
>     ('7', '123', '999', '123'),
>   ('8', '123', '999', '123'),
>     ('9', '123', '777', '123'),
>   ('10', '123', '777', '123'),
>   ('11', '123', '999', '123'),
>   ('12', '123', '999', '123'),
>     ('13', '123', '777', '123'),
>   ('14', '123', '777', '123'),
>   ('15', '999', '123', '123');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     id,
>     IF(`loss_id` <> 123,
>         @num:=@num + 1,
>         @num:=0) winstreek
> FROM
>     (SELECT 
>         *
>     FROM
>         wintable
>     WHERE
>         `player id` = 123
>     ORDER BY `id`) t1,
>     (SELECT @num:=0) a
> ```
>
> ```
> id | winstreek
> -: | --------:
>  1 |         1
>  2 |         2
>  3 |         3
>  4 |         4
>  5 |         0
>  6 |         1
>  7 |         2
>  8 |         3
>  9 |         4
> 10 |         5
> 11 |         6
> 12 |         7
> 13 |         8
> 14 |         9
> 15 |         0
> ```

> ```
> SELECT MAX(winstreek) winstreek
> FROM 
> (SELECT 
>     id,
>     IF(`loss_id` <> 123,
>         @num:=@num + 1,
>         @num:=0) winstreek
> FROM
>     (SELECT 
>         *
>     FROM
>         wintable
>     WHERE
>         `player id` = 123
>     ORDER BY `id`) t1,
>     (SELECT @num:=0) a) b;
> ```
>
> ```
> | winstreek |
> | --------: |
> |         9 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=80fc4d55b351f7a5213726e6a9a56102)*